# Count number of email conversations using Rapidminer

Tags: nlp, rapidminer

I am having an excel sheet which contains details about issue resolutions and one of the columns contains email conversation for that respective issue. In essence, each row has an email conversation for that issue (issueid being primary key for this data).
The email conversation format is consistent

From: "Name" \n
Date: "timestamp" \n
Subject:"Subject"  \n
To: "Name"  \n
"Body"

This pattern repeats again...

Now I need to find how many email conversations have happened for every issue using Rapidminer. I have read the excel and data is available for each row in Rapidminer... How can I accomplish this?

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of the number of emails for each issue, you would use the Aggregate operator.

Set the Group By parameter to be the issueid and set the Aggregation Attributes to be the email conversation attribute with an aggregation type of count.

Comment: Thanks for the response...Can you please let me know how to set email conversation attribute? It will be embedded in the text and how to retrieve it in an attribute dynamically...as the whole email thread (including From, To and Subject clause that I can use to find email count) will be present in a single row...

Comment: It's not clear whether there are multiple conversations in a single row,

Comment: yup... a single row denotes the whole email chain (can have multiple conversations back and forth with user and support team) for an issue... e.g. User raising the issue and then Support team replying and then user asking for clarifications etc... so multiple conversations within a single row... So, How do I scan the entire text within the cell, extract all email patterns (e.g. From and To combinations) and then taking the count of them, all of this while working on a single row...

Comment: You could treat the row with multiple emails as a document and use the Process Documents operator in the Text Mining extension to split it into multiple documents.  From there you could count the number of new documents created and add this an attribute. 

Other possibilities such as replacing all occurrences of the "subject:" text with a smaller string then comparing the length before and after to infer a count may be easier.

I'm not in front of the right computer so I can't give more details at the moment.